# CSS Display:inline-block | 3 columns | No floats

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a 3 column design, with out using any floats.

**HTML**

```
<header>This is a Header</header>
<div id="body">
    <div id="col-1" class="col">this is a column - this is a column - this is a column - this is a column</div>
    <div id="col-2" class="col">this is a column - this is a column - this is a column - this is a column</div>
    <div id="col-3" class="col">this is a column - this is a column - this is a column - this is a column</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    * {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    header {
        background:#4679BD;
        width:90%;
        height:70px;
        line-height:70px;
        font-size:20px;
        text-align:center;
        border:1px solid #333;
        margin:10px auto;
    }
    #body {
        width:700px;
        margin:auto;
        border:1px solid #333;
    }
    #body .col {
        display:inline-block;
        background:#ccc;
        height:500px;
        border:1px solid #333;
        margin:5px;
    }
    #body #col-1 {
        width:100px;
    }
    #body #col-2 {
        width:200px;
    }
    #body #col-3 {


   width:350px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chaos67731/fmZpr/5/

When I give the columns a width on the class ".col" the all stay to the top, but when I give each column a width by the ID and make them different, they step does as you will see in the link above.

What is a fix for this and why does it happen?

Answer (score 11):

By default, `inline-block` element's vertical alignment is `baseline`.

Simply set `vertical-align:top` on the `.col`.

```
#body .col {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[**Working jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/fmZpr/6/)

Comment: Amazing, I did not know that the alignment was defaulted to baseline. Very helpful and great added information.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
{
    vertical-align: top;
}
```